# Furnished Studio Apartment - Do eviscerators work?

Tags: infinifactory

The input multi-blocks of the Furnished Studio Apartment map seem immune to the Eviscerator.

*Is this intentional or a bug?*

I'm wondering if it's intentional to encourage use of Blocker plates.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the eviscerator anyway? You don't have any extra blocks in that level; you need everything you get.

Comment: @PaulZ Not on max rate :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some blocks are invulnerable.  I first noticed this with the Fusion Reactor Core.  Not being able to dissect that made things a lot more difficult.

I suggest, if you have a solution that requires input blocks to be broken, test that they can be broken before building a massive complicated machine that ultimately fails.